# Making a click on SAP Read Only Cell

Tags: automated-tests, sap-gui, tosca

My test step is failing saying that the sap table cell is a read only cell. I cannot make any click on it.

What could be the workaround for this.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it with **Tosca 10.2** and **SAP 7.40 P8** and everything is working fine for me.

I used **VA03** to test it. This is how it looks in SAP:

[image]

And this is how I did it in **Tosca** (SAP Engine 3.0 and SAP Engine 1.0):

[image]

However, I would recommend using the new **Engine 3.0**, because is much faster than **Tosca 10.2**.

Let me know if this was helpful for you.

Thanks,
Alert.

Comment: ..thanks for you suggestion here. I also tried it with classic engine and works fine for now. We are using tosca 10.0 P4. We need a update first ;P

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on disabled controls only works in recent versions by default.

Previously to that, you had to set a steering parameter called "**UseDisabledControlsForMouseOperations**" to "**True**" on your module attribute in order to click on disabled controls. (**Tosca 9.3 and lower**)

[image: UseDisabledControlsForMouseOperations[1]]

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ?